# PowerShell script to execute if threshold exceeded

Tags: powershell, if-statement, move

First off, sorry for the long post - I'm trying to be detailed!

I'm looking to automate a work around for an issue I discovered.  I have a worker that periodically bombs once the "working" directory has more than 100,000 files in it.  Preventatively I can stop the process and rename the working directory to "HOLD" and create new working dir to keep it going.  Then I move files from the HOLD folder(s) back into the working dir a little bit at a time until its caught up.

What I would like to do is automate the entire process via Task Scheduler with 2 PowerShell scripts.

**----SCRIPT 1----**

Here's the condition:

- If file count in working dir is greater than 60,000

I find that`( [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($Working)`is faster than `Get-ChildItem`.

The actions:

- `Stop-Service` for Service1, Service2, Service3
- `Rename-Item -Path  "C:\Prod\Working\" -NewName "Hold"` or "Hold1","2","3",etc.. if the folder already exists --I'm not particular about the numeration as long as it is consistent so if it's easier to let the system name it HOLD, HOLD(1), HOLD(2), etc.. or append the date after HOLD then that's fine.
- `New-Item C:\Prod\Working -type directory`
- `Start-Service` Service1, Service2, Service3

**---SCRIPT 2----**

Condition:

- If file count in working dir is less than 50,000

Actions:

- Move 5,000 files from HOLD* folder(s) --Move 5k files from the HOLD folder until empty, then skip the empty folder and start moving files from HOLD1.  This process should be dynamic and repeat to the next folders.

Before it comes up, I'm well aware it would be easier to simply move the files from the working folder to a Hold folder, but the size of the files can be very large and moving them always seems to take much longer.

I greatly appreciate any input and I'm eager to see some solid answers!

**EDIT**

Here's what I'm running for Script 2 -courtesy of Bacon

```js
#Setup
$restoreThreshold = 30000;  # Ensure there's enough room so that restoring $restoreBatchSize
$restoreBatchSize = 500;   # files won't push $Working's file count above $restoreThreshold
$Working = "E:\UnprocessedTEST\"
$HoldBaseDirectory = "E:\"

while (@(Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Working).Length -lt $restoreThreshold - $restoreBatchSize)
{
    $holdDirectory = Get-ChildItem -Path $HoldBaseDirectory -Directory -Filter '*Hold*' | 
    Select-Object -Last 1;
               
    if ($holdDirectory -eq $null)
    {
        # There are no Hold directories to process; don't keep looping
        break;
    }
# Restore the first $restoreBatchSize files from $holdDirectory and store the count of files restored
    $restoredCount = Get-ChildItem $holdDirectory -File `
    | Select-Object -First $restoreBatchSize | Move-Item -Destination $Working -PassThru | 
     Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Count';

   # If less than $restoreBatchSize files were restored then $holdDirectory is now empty; delete it
    if ($restoredCount -lt $restoreBatchSize)
    {
        Remove-Item -Path $holdDirectory; 
                                           }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got the building blocks to make this work.  What part are you having trouble with?  What is your question?

Comment: Paste your code into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first script could look like this:

```
$rotateThreshold = 60000;
$isThresholdExceeded = @(
    Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Working `
        | Select-Object -First ($rotateThreshold + 1) `
).Length -gt $rotateThreshold;
#Alternative: $isThresholdExceeded = @(Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Working).Length -gt $rotateThreshold;

if ($isThresholdExceeded)
{
    Stop-Service -Name 'Service1', 'Service2', 'Service3';

    try
    {
        $newName = 'Hold_{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss}' -f (Get-Date);

        Rename-Item -Path $Working -NewName $newName;
    }
    finally
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Working -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        Start-Service -Name 'Service1', 'Service2', 'Service3';
    }
}
```

The reason for assigning `$isThresholdExceeded` the way I am is because we don't care what the exact count of files is, just if it's above or below that threshold.  As soon as we know that threshold has been exceeded we don't need any further results from `Get-ChildItem` (or the same for `[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($Working)`), so as an opimization `Select-Object` will terminate the pipeline on the element after the threshold is reached.  In a directory with 100,000 files on an SSD I found this to be almost 40% faster than allowing `Get-ChildItem` to enumerate all files (4.12 vs. 6.72 seconds).  Other implementations using `foreach` or `ForEach-Object` proved to be slower than `@(Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Working).Length`.

As for generating the new name for the `'Hold'` directories, you could save and update an identifier somewhere, or just generate new names with an incrementing suffix until you find one that's not in use.  I think it's easier to just base the name on the current time.  As long as the script doesn't run more than once a second you'll know the name is unique, they'll sort just as well as numerals, plus it gives you a little diagnostic information (the time that directory was rotated out) for free.

Here's some basic code for the second script:

```
$restoreThreshold = 50000;
$restoreBatchSize = 5000;

# Ensure there's enough room so that restoring $restoreBatchSize
# files won't push $Working's file count above $restoreThreshold
while (@(Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Working).Length -lt $restoreThreshold - $restoreBatchSize)
{
    $holdDirectory = Get-ChildItem -Path $HoldBaseDirectory -Directory -Filter 'Hold_*' `
        | Select-Object -First 1;

    if ($holdDirectory -eq $null)
    {
        # There are no Hold directories to process; don't keep looping
        break;
    }

    # Restore the first $restoreBatchSize files from $holdDirectory and store the count of files restored
    $restoredCount = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $holdDirectory.FullName `
        | Select-Object -First $restoreBatchSize `
        | Move-Item -Destination $Working -PassThru `
        | Measure-Object `
        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Count';

    # If less than $restoreBatchSize files were restored then $holdDirectory is now empty; delete it
    if ($restoredCount -lt $restoreBatchSize)
    {
        Remove-Item -Path $holdDirectory.FullName;
    }
}
```

As noted in the comment before the `while` loop, the condition is ensuring that the count of files in `$Working` is at least `$restoreBatchSize` files away from `$restoreThreshold` so that if `$restoreBatchSize` files are restored it won't exceed the threshold in the process.  If you don't care about that, or the chosen threshold already accounts for that, you change the condition to compare against `$restoreThreshold` instead of `$restoreThreshold - $restoreBatchSize`.  Alternatively, leave the condition the same and change `$restoreThreshold` to `55000`.

The way I've written the loop, on each iteration at most `$restoreBatchSize` files will be restored from the first `'Hold_*'` directory it finds, then the file count in `$Working` is reevaluated.  Considering that, as I understand it, there are files being added and removed from `$Working` external to this script and simultaneous to its execution, this might be the safest approach and also the simplest approach.  You could certainly enhance this by calculating how far below `$restoreThreshold` you are and performing the necessary number of batch restores, from one or more `'Hold_*'` directories, all in one iteration of the loop.

Comment: Right, the second script would then enumerate the list of `Hold*` directories and process each of them from there. The second script was a little unclear in terms of whether it runs on the same schedule as the first script and what you mean by wanting the process to be "dynamic". As for the `if` statement, the call to `ForEach-Object` accomplishes the same thing as the code prefixed with `#Alternative: `, it's just attempting to do it more efficiently since you're working with a potentially large number of files.

Comment: So the important part for the second script is so that I can set it to run every couple of hours to move 5,000 files from the hold folders back into the working folder so that they be processed. This *could* run side by side with the 1st script as it should only start moving files back to the working dir if the number of files currently present in "WORKING" is less than 50,000.  This leave me with a 10,000 file delta to work with and should ensure that processing both live and backlogged files never stops.  I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I reread the question and edited my comment after seeing the second paragraph covered what the second script is doing.  So you're just moving files out of the working directory to get under the 100,000 files "limit", and now I see that you're moving them _back_ for processing once it's "safe".  And I assume that files are automatically removed from the working directory once the external methods have processed them, but they're queued for processing faster than they're processed?

Comment: Thanks very much for your input!  I'm testing the second script but I'm getting errors.                        Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\UnprocessedHOLD3' because it does not exist.
At line:20 char:22
+     $restoredCount = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $holdDirectory |
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\system32\UnprocessedHOLD3:String) [Get-Chi 
   ldItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: What is the actual location of the `HOLD3` directory?  Is it a child of a `C:\Windows\system32\Unprocessed` directory?  Is it correct that `C:\Windows\system32` is the base directory for these file operations?

Comment: I added the code I'm running to my original post so you may view it easier.

Comment: My mistake.  `Get-ChildItem -Path $holdDirectory -File` will look at the `Name` (not `FullName`) property of `$holdDirectory` as a path relative to the current location (PowerShell's working directory).  It should be `Get-ChildItem -Path $holdDirectory.FullName -File` (or, equivalently, `$holdDirectory | Get-ChildItem -File`).  Similarly, should be `Get-ChildItem -Path $HoldBaseDirectory.FullName -Directory -Filter '*Hold*'` and `Remove-Item -Path $holdDirectory.FullName`.  (This is what I get for switching to parameters where usually I'd pass a path via the pipeline!)